# SQL Server 2008: Execution plan contains wrong data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

Consider the following situation:

1. There is an xml that contains data @XmlData
2. The @XmlData is extracted into a relational table (@ItemList)
3. A table variable is defined (@Table)
4. The data extracted from 2 db tables (tblCdbA0 and tblCdbG2) into @Table using exists clause

Here is a code sample:

```
--1. There is an xml that contains data @XmlData 
declare @XmlData xml = '
<Root>
      <Item rid="522822E251CA11D18F1400A02427D15E" />
</Root>'

--2. The @XmlData is extracted into a relational table (@ItemList)
declare @ItemList table (ItemRid char(32) primary key);
insert into @ItemList(ItemRid)
select Tab.rid
from ( select Item.Rid.value('@rid','char(32)') rid
       from @XmlData.nodes('(/Root)[1]/Item') Item(Rid)) Tab
group by Tab.rid

--3. A table variable is defined (@table)
declare @Table TABLE 
(
    Rid char(32) primary key
   ,Rid1 char(32)
   ,Rid2 char(32)
)

--4. The data extracted from 2 db tables (tblCdbA0 and tblCdbG2) into @Table using exists clause
insert into @Table(Rid,Rid1,Rid2)
select A0.A0RID, A0.T4RID, A0.T6RID
from tblCdbA0 A0 with (nolock)
where 
exists (select null 
         from tblCdbG2 G2 with(nolock)
         inner join @ItemList Items
         on Items.ItemRid = G2.G0RID 
         where A0.A0RID=G2.A0RID)
```

The table tblCdbG2 contains **63582** rows.
Let's look what actual execution plan of the last statement shows us:

[image: Query execution plan]

The execution plan shows that number of data rows that are extracted from tblCdbG2 table equal to **807** rows instead of **63582**.

In my view, the number of rows that are extracted from tblCdbG2 must be **63582**. After inner join with @ItemList is applied the number of rows must be **807**.

What is the reason to show already filtered rows number before inner join?

**Update**:

I have slightly modified the existing query and the plan shows the same value **807**.

The query:

```
select G2.A0RID 
         from tblCdbG2 G2 with(nolock)
         inner join @ItemList Items
         on Items.ItemRid = G2.G0RID
```

The plan:

[image: Slightly modified query in EXISTS]

Comment: Run the EXISTS sub-query separately: what then?

Comment: @gbn: the plan shows the same number of rows **807**..

Comment: Why do you constantly use the nolock hint?

Comment: @Andrew: Since the data in the tables tblCdbA0, tblCdbG2 are almost static, I use with (nolock) hint in order to avoid shared locking on the tables.

Comment: Nolock still issues a Sch-S lock, and multiple Shared-Locks will not block each other.

Comment: Your are right, in this case does not makes much sense to use with (nolock) hint, since the data is almost static and Shared-Locks are not blocking each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested loop to left is pulling every row from @ItemList. For each row from @Item list it is using an index (Clustered Index Seek) to find just the matching row(s) in tblCdbG2. It does not first extract all 60+K rows.